# Docker daemon does not bind to TCP6

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, docker, ipv6

I have a composition with the default networking configuration and a definition such as:

```
services:

  myservice:
    image: someimage
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

The service properly binds to IPv4 and can be accessed as expected. Since a week or two, the service does no longer bind to IPv6 which previously worked without problems. Running `netstat -plnt` shows me that the docker-proxy is not listening on IPv6 ports:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1936/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1898/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      811/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1883/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::2377                 :::*                    LISTEN      1283/dockerd
tcp6       0      0 :::7946                 :::*                    LISTEN      1283/dockerd
```

So you can see that ports 80 and 443  are exposed on `tcp` but not `tcp6`. Searching for this issue I can only find the reversed problem (docker is listening on IPv6 but not IPv4).

When trying to bin the port with `socat` the port is reported in use (while `netstat` states it is not). Binding port 81 to the IPv4 address on port 80 allows me to access the server via IPv6 so there is no routing issue anywhere else.

```
sudo socat TCP6-LISTEN:80,fork TCP4:127.0.0.1:80
2021/01/13 16:08:50 socat[26572] E bind(5, {AF=10 [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:80}, 28): Address already in use
```

`docker inspect` shows the following information:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "d5fdebb4de954a4d7c1800490e44d0f53c4ee827775edb8ba286583e888eaa07",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {
        "443/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "443"
            }
        ],
        "80/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "80"
            }
        ]
    },
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/d5fdebb4de95",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "",
    "Gateway": "",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "",
    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "MacAddress": "",
    "Networks": {
        "docker_default": {
            "IPAMConfig": null,
            "Links": null,
            "Aliases": [
                "d8acfbf724cf"
            ],
            "NetworkID": "87b6b52c779252614553040f217f9f2310ee3cce5f1a450f6a8210e8ea411b5a",
            "EndpointID": "a6bdf4d85641a043c25812ac0759a7ad872a3ee15ff7ea0e3ddf6b2405967737",
            "Gateway": "172.20.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.20.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
            "DriverOpts": null
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a semi-intentional<sup>1</sup> change in Docker 20.10.2, see the related discussion here: https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/issues/2607. Looks like a [fix](https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/pull/2608) is [underway](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/41908).

In the meantime, downgrading to 20.10.1 works for me:

```bsh
sudo apt install docker-ce=5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-focal \
                 docker-ce-cli=5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-focal
sudo apt-mark hold docker-ce docker-ce-cli
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Semi-intentional because, apparently, this feature was never intended to be used this way. I’m as surprised as you are…

Comment: Thanks. Updated docker and can confirm this is fixed in `20.10.12`.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed this by moving the docker ports and creating a `socat` proxy with `systemd` as described in [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24379#issuecomment-569082209). Steps are as follows:

Move the ports of your container, e.g. `8080:80` and `8443:443`

Install [socat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat)

```
apt-get install socat
```

Create two `systemd` services that will use `socat` to listen on both IPv4 and IPv6 and forward the traffic to the IPv4 endpoint of your service:

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/socat-tcp-80.service

[Unit] 
Description=Socat TCP:80 
After=network.target

[Service] 
Type=simple 
User=root 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/socat TCP6-LISTEN:80,,su=nobody,fork,reuseaddr TCP4:127.0.0.1:8080
Restart=on-failure

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save the file and create another one for port `443`.

Start the services and enable them at boot:

```
systemctl start socat-tcp-80
systemctl start socat-tcp-443
systemctl enable socat-tcp-80
systemctl enable socat-tcp-443
```

You can use `journalctl -feu socat-tcp-80` to fetch the logs of your service.

I don't know why the behavior of docker changed recently, but this workaround allows us to support IPv6 nevertheless.

Comment: While this might be a temporary workaround, it does not fix the underlying problem.

Comment: ( and you have the wrong ip's since your ingress proxy will see the host's ip  e.g. 172.17.0.1 )